# Freshly downloaded images get error message: couldn't recognize data in image file. But old images work?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, png

I want to use images in my GUI made with tkinter and python. My problem is that images that i downloaded from Google during the project dosent work and getting the error message is: couldn't recognize data in image file. However old images from before i started the project works, and if it is same type (.png) and in the same folder. I tried with several different folders and they all work with old images, but not with new. This is the method i use:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

win = tk.Tk()

photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\My\Folder\myPicture.png')
photolabel=Label(win, image=photo)
photolabel.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: How are you downloading these fresh image.

Comment: I go to google, right click the image, save as: and put it in my folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tkinter does not recognize all image formats. The safest format for tkinter is .gif; you can try using an image editing program to resave your files as .gifs. Or you can install the pillow module and use that to load images, as that will recognize many more types of images.

```
py -m pip install pillow
```

And you would use it like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
win = tk.Tk()

photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'C:\My\Folder\myPicture.png'))
photolabel=tk.Label(win, image=photo)
photolabel.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: AFAIK, newer versions of `tkinter` supports png well.

Comment: @CoolCloud .png has a number of forms, and I don't think all of the compression types are supported. Also, a .png name does not mean it's actually png format, it's not uncommon for people to accidentally name images with the wrong extension. Most programs ignore the extension anyway so it goes unnoticed.

Comment: True about the renaming png file, it might be the cause too.

Comment: It works! I also tried this method with PIL but i think PIL was downloaded in the wrong folder, i moved it to the right folder and got it to work. Thanks for the help!